# IEFrame.dll error header

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm getting an IEFrame.dll error and design errors on a call button on this [website](http://asprayni.com/) on IE9.  It might do it on IE7,8 as well, I'm not sure.

Anyway, what is an IEFrame.dll error and how can I fix it?  The functionality and design both work perfectly on Firefox, Chrome etc.

Many thanks in advance,

Phil

Comment: Does the website require a plugin? What is `tel:0800-xxx-xxxx` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found it usually comes from intranet, I have fix with the help of this - -

http://networkingstudy.net/forums/index.php/topic,1126

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late. But I have been struggling with this error to on an https page. 
[image]

Looks like this is a microsft has acknowledged this error and we need to update some secutiry settings. This like will be useful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2601307/en-us